# Getting information from Navy service record if date of death unknown?

Tags: military-records, world-war-2, united-kingdom, navy

I am helping a friend research her father who was born in 1917.  The only document she has, of his, is his marriage certificate...giving his name, father's name and name of spouse and profession.

He was a Navy Stoker with a service number starting with D/KX and followed by six digits.  He married in Birmingham, in 1944.  There is believed to be a connection to Canada.

Can I get information from his Navy service record if his date of death is unknown?

Comment: Welcome to G&FH.SE!  I've edited your question because our [guidelines for on-topic questions](http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) are to NOT include information in questions "that would allow identification of any living (or possibly) living individual by somebody reading this site. In practice, this means details about anyone born in the last 100 years, whether they are believed to be deceased or not, and whether or not they have given their permission."  While you are waiting for answers, you may be able to get some clues from other questions here about WW2.

Comment: From your original message, I am guessing that you have a marriage certificate, because you said you had his name, his father's name, and the name of the woman he married in 1944, and a service number.  Feel free to edit your question, using the edit link underneath, to say that you have particular documents and which information you have without telling us the actual information.  Also, we encourage people to ask *specific* questions, so I have removed the tags for immigration and vital records, focusing on the military service in this question.

Comment: This is similar to http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/3785/1006 but I am assuming that you don't know what happened to your friend's father and thus won't have a death certificate.

Comment: Another Meta Q&A that may be worth reviewing for ideas about how to try and find out about this sailor without identifying him is at http://meta.genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/1900/how-much-detail-should-be-included-in-questions-about-ww1-and-ww2-service-member  Also, if you are still stuck finding him after the date of his 100th birthday in about 2 years time you should feel free to reinstate his name, and precise data/location of birth then.

Comment: Do you have a date of birth?  Otherwise, with the info your friend has, it may be possible to find an entry in the GRO indices and order a birth certificate (assuming the name isn't too common).  With a birth date and a name, it may be possible to find a death record in Canada and then provide that information to order the service record.