# Finding father who was in UK Royal Navy during 1960s?

Tags: united-kingdom, navy, 1960s

I am looking for my father who was an able seaman in the 1960's in the United Kingdom.

He was on the Royal Navy ship HMS Brighton.

I do have an ID that starts d/j......

Are there any sites I can go to that will establish this info?

Comment: Yes, it was in the UK.

Comment: http://www.godfreydykes.info/ROYAL%20NAVY%20OFFICIAL%20NUMBERS%20%5BRATINGS%5D.htm suggests the numbering *might* be Navy numbering.

Comment: He was on HMS Brighton if that helps?

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour].  Please take care as you ask this question that our privacy policy in the [help/on-topic] does not allow the name and any other identifying details of anyone born less than 100 years ago to be posted except within those guidelines.  Your question is fine in that respect so far.

Comment: sorry if that was obvious, I've no idea about this as I haven't found it easy to find anything relevant via my internet searches.

Comment: Review the suggestions in comments at http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/9285/104 which is very similar (I'm assuming you can't prove your father's death).

Comment: Please don't apologise for what you don't know -- none of us know everything.

Comment: Thank you. I don't have his date of birth, just his Navy ID which I'm hoping will help unlock other information.

Comment: I can't move to chat as this is the first time I've posted anything.

Comment: Can anyone advise as to where I ought to go next for info to positively ID him?

Comment: I have a name and assumed place of origin

Comment: How do I verify his birth/death details?

Answer (score 1):

If your father is no longer alive, and you are his 'Next of Kin' you can apply for his service record. You have to do this direct from the Royal Navy and on payment of a fee they will send you his records. See their website for information on how to do this (item 3 on the page). [Royal Navy Research Archive](http://www.royalnavyresearcharchive.org.uk/Records_page.htm)

If he is not deceased then they will not supply the details, and you will have to explore other options in searching for living people.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to access uk military records through a link on Scotlandspeople.govt.uk however I did have to pay for the acccess which I found disappointing because after paying there was no further information than the free data. It was a record from 1861.