# Which ship did my father serve on with RNP 2420

Tags: world-war-2, united-kingdom, navy

My father (now deceased) served in a Royal Navy Party in 45. RNP 2420 - Force W.

How do I find which ship he served on? His number was P/LX 24536. His name was Peter Lornie. He began service in 1940 as a Leading Steward and ended the war as a a/COG Steward. Prior to the Far East expedition he served aboard HMS Queen Elizabeth until 1941 and then on board HMS Sirius until 1943 when he was hospitalised (?) after being injured.

I have his service record.

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] which leads to the [help/on-topic] and our privacy policy that means we need to take precautions when discussing anybody born less than 100 years ago. Can you confirm whether that is the case for your father, please?

Comment: It's not exactly a duplicate but http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/2264/tracing-records-of-royal-navy-personnel-from-world-war-2 is probably relevant

Comment: @ColeValleyGirl In this instance I am not sure what "see above" is referencing.  I haven't pulled this one up on privacy because the asker has not told us when his father was born.  I'm assuming that it was no later than 1916.  Where are the "other places" that Richard has commented "that he has the service record"?  If not in the question, answers or comments attached to them, then I think it is important information to have edited into the question.

Comment: @ColeValleyGirl - so that's where the comment delete option is! I was looking beneath the comment! Yes good point about transience though answers can develop through the exchange of comments, so not too transient!

Answer (score 4):

It appears that a Royal Naval Party is often a shore based establishment or an amphibious establishment, so the questions "which ship he served on" may be moot.

[NAVAL PARTIES of the ROYAL NAVY, 1942-1991](http://www.naval-history.net/xBW-RNNavalParties.htm) shows the places where RNP 2420 served (some of them pretty land-locked like Delhi) but including a couple of periods on H.M.S. Bulolo:

> 2420: Flag Officer Force W & Staff (*attached to Admiralty 10.44 – 11.44/left UK for Delhi 20.11.44/to Chittagong area 12.44/ to Burma (Akyab) 02.45/ Force W to Delhi 05.45/ in India to 08.45/embarked BULOLO*) Chittagong 01.45/Akyab 02-03.45/Kyaukpyu, Ramree Is 04-05.45/Delhi 06-07.45/Bombay08-09.45/BULOLO 09-10.45/ Singapore 11.45 – 01.46/ title lapsed 02.46

The [Imperial War Museum](http://www.iwm.org.uk/collections/item/object/1060034930) has material from January 1946 which refers to "Force W, part of the amphibious force that landed troops in Malaya" and [this site](http://www.unithistories.com/officers/RN_officersO.html) mentions at least one office "serving in South-East Asia, on the planning staff for operations in the Arakan and Malaya, the so-called Force W" between January and December 1945.

War diaries such as the one [here](http://www.naval-history.net/xDKWD-EF1945.htm) can give you some idea of what Force W as involved in.

And [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMS_Bulolo) mentions HMS Bulolo:

> Following another refit, the Bulolo was sent in 1945 to be the Headquarters Ship and flagship of Rear Admiral Benjamin Martin for 'Force W' off Malaya commanding the Allies retaking of South East Asia from Japanese forces. In September 1945, Bulolo was used to accept the Japanese surrender at Singapore.

The original ships logs for Bulolo for her time in the Far East are held at [The National Archives](http://discovery.nationalarchives.gov.uk/browse/r/h/C1585360?cK=!&sUp=true&sK=C1585360)

Comment: I don't believe I'd added much value to the answers you've already received on more specialist forums, but the info might be of use to others with similar queries who come here

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at http://www.naval-history.net/xBW-RNNavalParties.htm . Your answer is there.

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] because our focussed Q&A format works differently (and I think better) than bulletin boards, discussion forums and most other Q&A site,  I had a quick look on that page but could not find the answer that @RichardLornie is seeking.  If you did could you copy/paste the relevant part into your answer, please?